# Error: .eslintrc.js: Configuration for rule "no-empty-interface" is invalid:

Tags: typescript, eslint, eslintrc, typescript-eslint

Trying to add a rule that says it's okay to have an empty interface such as below. Please note I am trying to add this to the eslintrc.js file - is this correct?

```
interface RoutesProps {}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution was to set `@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface': 0,` to '0' rather than false.

```
module.exports = {
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser', // Specifies the ESLint parser
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 2020, // Allows for the parsing of modern ECMAScript features
        sourceType: 'module', // Allows for the use of imports
        ecmaFeatures: {
            jsx: true, // Allows for the parsing of JSX
        },
    },
    settings: {
        react: {
            version: 'detect', // Tells eslint-plugin-react to automatically detect the version of React to use
        },
    },
    extends: [
        'plugin:react/recommended', // Uses the recommended rules from @eslint-plugin-react
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended', // Uses the recommended rules from the @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
        'prettier/@typescript-eslint', // Uses eslint-config-prettier to disable ESLint rules from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin that would conflict with prettier
        'plugin:prettier/recommended', // Enables eslint-plugin-prettier and eslint-config-prettier. This will display prettier errors as ESLint errors. Make sure this is always the last configuration in the extends array.
    ],
    rules: {
        'no-use-before-define': ['error', { functions: false, classes: false, variables: true }],
        'no-shadow': 'warn',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface': 0,
        // Place to specify ESLint rules. Can be used to overwrite rules specified from the extended configs
        // e.g. "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off",
    },
};
```